# Show all data from sql server database into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I need help in creating a website where I could show all the data in the `t-sql` table into a web table form. But all my code did is showing only the last data in my database. i'm new in this web environment. i'm doing this in `html5` and `c#` code.

```
if (Byday.Checked == true)
    {
        con.Open();//database control
        string sql = "select top 30 * from " + locID + " where date = '" + txtStartDate.Text+ "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        //execute datareader
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Label2.Text = dr["ID"].ToString();
                Label3.Text = dr["date"].ToString();
                Label4.Text = dr["data"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

and is there a way for the system search the data just by month/year?? that would help me so much. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is you are selecting only 30 records. Select all the records in the table:

```
string sql = "select id, date, data from " + locID + " where date = '" + txtStartDate.Text+ "'";
```

There are different approaches to search by month and year, check the following functions which can convert your `date` to:

- [Year](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) - gets the year from date
- [Month](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) - gets the month number from date
- `datename(MONTH, yourdate)` to get name of the month

So, if you need to get all records from year `2013` you can do use the following `where` clause:

```
WHERE YEAR(date) > 2013
```

Comment: i'm still having problem as it only show the last row of the table data.  i need it to show the top 30 data in the website. i have run the query and it run fine but when i want to view it in my webpage, it only show the last row of the database of each column.

Comment: is it possible for me to show the data in a table form with the control??

Comment: i just notice that the query i used only search for date that yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00. I need it to search the whole date in date yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00 until yyyy/mm/dd 23:59:99... how do i do that?

Comment: Just add the conditions in the `WHERE` clause like this: `WHERE date> yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00 AND date < yyyy/mm/dd 23:59:99`